# I have trouble understanding the return command in recursion

Tags: python, recursion, factorial

```
def fac(n):
    if (n < 1):
        return 1
    else:
        n * fac(n-1)
print fac(4)
```

Why does return command cause the function to go back up and multiply the factorials? I have trouble understanding this.

Comment: It would help if you used a real language to write this; it is hard to explain how code works in a made-up language.

Comment: You're missing a `return` in your function's "else" branch. To go about understanding this, try breaking it down into a sequence of single instructions. Write them down, in exact order, starting with your `print` command.

Comment: @scott hunter i thought I wrote the code in python. I noticed some syntax errors and fixed it

Comment: @tehhowch ok thanks. I’m know that the code starts with 4*fac(3) then 3*fac(2), 2*fac(1),  1*fac(0) and then return 1 is called. I am confused at this part because I thought the code would terminate with a return command but instead it goes back up doing 1*fac(0)=0, 2*fac(1)=2, 3*fac(2)=6 , 4*fac(3)=24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1). You need to write a return in your code.

```
def fac(n):
if (n < 1):
    return 1
else:
    return n * fac(n-1)
print(fac(4))
```

2). I am uploading a picture which will help you to understand the concept of recursion. Follow the arrow from start to end in the picture.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the `call stack`. The way this code needs to operate is for every `fac(n)` is equal to `n * (n-1) * (n-2) ... (n - n + 1)`.

Your code was wrong. For a `recursive` function to work, you must be returning a value each time. You were getting `None` back because you never returned anything.

```
def fac(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return n * fac(n - 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    num = 2
    print(fac(num))
```

Keep practicing `recursion`. It is extremely useful and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

For more of a *why it works* than *how it works* perspective:

Calling a function recursively *is no different than calling a different function*: it just happens to execute the same set of instructions.  You don't worry about Python getting confused between locals and parameters of different functions, or knowing where to return to; this is no different.  In fact, if each recursive invocation had its own name instead of re-using the same name, you probably wouldn't be here.

Showing that it works *properly* is a bit different, because you need to make sure the recursion ends at some point.  But this is no different than worrying about infinite loops.